# JSoup Malformed URL Exception

Tags: java, arraylist, jsoup

I am trying to use JSoup to open a list of links I've stored in an ArrayList named arrayLinks. When I run the code to open a link in the ArrayList, I get a Malformed URL Exception.However, if I take the Malformed Links and hardcode them into the application, I get no errors. I have tried looking at several other posts using StringFormatters or UTF-8, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Code that Doesn't Work:

```
article = Jsoup.connect(arrayLinks.get(i)).get()
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "https://www.sbnation.com/college-football-recruiting/2014/7/3/5715252/cordell-broadus-recruit-scouting-report-sure-handed-receiver"
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:523)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:470)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:132)
```

Code that Works:

```
article = Jsoup.connect("https://www.sbnation.com/college-football-recruiting/2014/7/3/5715252/cordell-broadus-recruit-scouting-report-sure-handed-receiver").get()
```

Comment: How do you define the ArrayList? How do you add items to it?

Comment: The problem might be with encoding of urls you are adding to your arrayList. Verify the code that adds urls to your array list.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me.

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WebScraping{  
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{ 

       ArrayList<String> arrayLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
       arrayLinks.add("https://www.google.com");
       arrayLinks.add("https://www.youtube.com");
       arrayLinks.add("https://www.facebook.com");
       arrayLinks.add("https://www.sbnation.com/college-football-recruiting/2014/7/3/5715252/cordell-broadus-recruit-scouting-report-sure-handed-receiver");

       for(int i=0; i<arrayLinks.size(); i++) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(arrayLinks.get(i)).get();
            System.out.println(doc.title());
           }
    }  
}
```

**Output**

> Google
>
> YouTube
>
> Facebook - ??? ?? ?? ???? ?? ????
>
> Cordell Broadus
>   recruit scouting report: Sure-handed receiver - SBNation.com

I think you did not defined  **ArrayList as String type** that's why you are getting malformed url exception.

Answer (score 2):

Did you solve this?

It looks like the problem is the quotes.  The source for `java.net.URL` shows it wouldn't have quoted any malformed URL:

```
throw new MalformedURLException("no protocol: "+original);
```

Clearly this will produce the exception you're reporting:

```
Jsoup.connect("\"https://www.sbnation.com/college-football-recruiting/2014/7/3/5715252/cordell-broadus-recruit-scouting-report-sure-handed-receiver\"").get();
```

... the result being:

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "https://www.sbnation.com/college-football-recruiting/2014/7/3/5715252/cordell-broadus-recruit-scouting-report-sure-handed-receiver"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:76)
```